# whether the following judgement is correct?

Tags: limits, inequality

I have an expression $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}=\alpha$ where $0<\alpha<1,$    $\alpha$  is a known fixed positive constant,  Then can I conclude that $|f(x)|\leq \beta |x|$ $\hspace{0.2 cm}$   for $0<\beta<1$ for sufficiently large values of $|x|?$ Further whether $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal? And how to prove this?

Comment: You can conclude that when $\beta > \alpha$, but not for $\beta \leqslant \alpha$.

Comment: Daniel, can you tell how to prove this?

Comment: For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $R(\varepsilon)$ such that $$\alpha - \varepsilon < \frac{\lvert f(x)\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert} < \alpha + \varepsilon$$ whenever $\lvert x\rvert > R(\varepsilon)$. Take $\varepsilon \leqslant \beta - \alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Will expand on Daniel's answer:

It is correct for $\beta>\alpha$: Let $\beta>\alpha$ and assume there is a sequence $\{x_n\}\to\infty$ such that $|f(x_n)|>\beta|x_n|$ then for any M, there is $x_M>M$ such that $\frac{|f(x_M)|}{|x_M|}>\beta>\alpha$, contradicting the known $\lim_{x\to\infty}=\alpha$.

It is NOT correct for $\beta<\alpha$:  using somewhat the same arguments.

It is NOT correct for $\beta=\alpha$: For $\beta=\alpha$ just use the example $f(x)=\alpha\cdot x +\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=0.5x$, and take $\beta =0.2$.